# serve string as variable

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i want to get value from input element using id and save the value in variable
but it need to be dynamic

i have id in html that id's name is same as variable name

as my routhine mathod is

```
let one = document.getElementById("one").value
let two= document.getElementById("two").value
let three= document.getElementById("three").value

console.log(one,two,three) // value1,value2,value2
```

but i want do it dynamic
i have tried this but not worked

```
let one,two,three; //declared variable
let valueArray = ["one","two","three"]  // i want loop through variable so declare varibles array in string
valueArray.forEach(element => {   // loop over array
   element = document.getElementById(element)  
});

console.log(one,two,three) // undefined,undefined,undefined
```

so any idea to doing this dynamic

Comment: Is this truly a `react` question? This code appears to be plain JS, and if you're using `react` you should very rarely be using DOM selectors.

Comment: You're also overwriting the `element` parameter, which goes out of scope each loop. I'm not exactly sure what your objective is here, can you update your question with the desired result vs what you're currently getting?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the found element!

Comment: based on your code, assuming everything else is working properly, `element.value` should have your input field's value.

Comment: As long as you're explicitly declaring the variables `one`, `two`, `three`, you are not doing anything "dynamically".  You'll need to use an array or object so that it can be appended to dynamically.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to write to the window object, which saves values as global variables:

```
const valueArray = ["one","two","three"];

for (const value of idArray) {
  window[value] = getElementById(value).value;
}
```

Setting variables like this is harder to read than regular assignments, so be aware that this would not be considered best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Place your variables in an object and then update the values:

```js
    var values = {}
    let valueArray = ["one","two","three"]
    valueArray.forEach(element => {   // loop over array
       values[element] = document.getElementById(element)  
    });
    
    console.log(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
const [ one, two, three] = ['one', 'two', 'three'].map(item => document.getElementById(item).value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements with ID already is in `window` object, so all you need to do is use `window[element]`

```js
let valueArray = ["one","two","three"];

valueArray.forEach(element => {   // loop over array
   console.log(window[element]);
});
```

```html
<div id="one">ONE</div>
<div id="two">TWO</div>
<div id="three">THREE</div>
```